# Applying restrictions on prompt box

Tags: javascript

I'm taking user input using the `prompt` box. I want to apply some restrictions on the prompt box so that user can't input anything other than "digits" and the input length should be just one character. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: prompt box means text box?

Comment: @PSR: `prompt` is a standard browser function. It asks the user for a line of input.

Comment: No, you just could add an check, and if it doesnt "match" return the prompt...but it is not user friendly... VisioN's Answer is the way to go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No.

The behaviour of standard dialog boxes, like `alert`, `confirm` or `prompt`, can't be changed. You should implement your own dialogs or use third party implementations, e.g. [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/).

Answer (score 1):

You can not change prompt but you can make alert if user enters something you did not want. For example:.

```
var input = prompt("Enter just one character that is not 'digit'");

if (input.length > 1) {
    alert ("You have entered more than one character.")
    } else if (!isNaN(input)) {    
    alert("Thing you entered is 'digit'.");
}
```